# How to crop/resize texture array in Metal

Tags: metal

Say I have a N-channel `MPSImage` or texture array that is based on `MTLTexture`.

How do I crop a region from it, copying all the N channels, but changing "pixel size"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll just address the crop case, since the resize case involves resampling and is marginally more complicated. Let me know if you really need that.

Let's assume your source `MPSImage` is a 12 feature channel (3 slice) image that is 128x128 pixels, that your destination image is an 8 feature channel image (2 slices) that is 64x64 pixels, and that you want to copy the bottom-right 64x64 region of the last two slices of the source into the destination.

There is no API that I'm aware of that allows you to copy from/to multiple slices of an array texture at once, so you'll need to issue multiple blit commands to cover all the slices:

```swift
let sourceRegion = MTLRegionMake3D(64, 64, 0, 64, 64, 1)
let destOrigin = MTLOrigin(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
let firstSlice = 1
let lastSlice = 2 // inclusive

let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
let blitEncoder = commandBuffer.makeBlitCommandEncoder()

for slice in firstSlice...lastSlice {
    blitEncoder.copy(from: sourceImage.texture,
                     sourceSlice: slice,
                     sourceLevel: 0,
                     sourceOrigin: sourceRegion.origin,
                     sourceSize: sourceRegion.size,
                     to: destImage.texture,
                     destinationSlice: slice - firstSlice,
                     destinationLevel: 0,
                     destinationOrigin: destOrigin)
}
    
blitEncoder.endEncoding()
commandBuffer.commit()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you want to crop, but keep in mind that the MPSCNN layers can work on a smaller portion of your MPSImage. Just set the `offset` and `clipRect` properties and the layer will only work on that region of the source image.

In fact, you could do your crops this way using an `MPSCNNNeuronLinear`. Not sure if that is any faster or slower than using a blit encoder but it's definitely simpler.

**Edit:** added a code example. This is typed from memory so it may have small errors, but this is the general idea:

```swift
// Declare this somewhere:
let linearNeuron = MPSCNNNeuronLinear(a: 1, b: 0)
```

Then when you run your neural network, add the following:

```swift
let yourImage: MPSImage = ...
let commandBuffer = ...

// This describes the size of the cropped image.
let imgDesc = MPSImageDescriptor(...)

// If you're going to use the cropped image in other layers 
// then it's a good idea to make it a temporary image.
let tempImg = MPSTemporaryImage(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, imageDescriptor: imgDesc)

// Set the cropping offset:
linearNeuron.offset = MPSOffset(x: ..., y: ..., z: 0)

// The clip rect is the size of the output image.
linearNeuron.clipRect = MTLRegionMake(0, 0, imgDesc.width, imgDesc.height)

linearNeuron.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, sourceImage: yourImage, destinationImage: tempImg)

// Here do your other layers, taking tempImg as input.
. . .

commandBuffer.commit()
```

Comment: I upvoted both the answers, but @warrenm's one seem to be more suitable. I like your idea as well.

Comment: can you also provide a simple code, on how to crop `MPSImage` with `NeuronLinear`? I see that I need to set `a` to `1` and `b` to `0`, but not sure what to do next.

Comment: If 'yourImage' is a 3-channel image (e.g. RGB) and 'tempImg' is a 1-channel image: How could I achieve that channel change using a linearNeuron? The dest-region should either contain just the 'R' or even better a gray representation. When I just specify the ImageDescriptors with (,,3) and (,,1) the whole thing crashes.